# ng-repeat How to void duplicate key but preserve row data?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a table which looks this the image below
[image]

As you can see the text on the right side is duplicated because each row represents different data, I want to have distict rows and i want to display the data for each e.g 'فدية' in the same row.

The angular-code:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.reportData | groupBy :'ProductNameAR'">

    <tr ng-repeat="item in value">
        <td>{{item.ProductNameAR}}</td>
        <%-- CHANNEL '  نقاط البيع' --%>
        <td>{{item.ChannelID == 1 ? item.Amount : 0}}</td>
        <td>{{item.ChannelID == 1 ? item.Value :  0}}</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <%-- CHANNEL ' المسلخ' --%>
        <td>{{item.ChannelID == 4 ? item.Amount : 0}}</td>
        <td>{{item.ChannelID == 4 ? item.Value : 0}}</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <%-- CHANNEL  ' السوق الإلكتروني' --%>
        <td>{{item.ChannelID == 2 ? item.Amount : 0}}</td>
        <td>{{item.ChannelID == 2 ? item.Value : 0}}</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>950</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The Json Data i am receiving looks something like this:

[image]

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: It is really hard to reproduce a problem when the sample data is a picture.

Answer (score 1):

filter the duplicate before rendering on the view 
takes the raw data and filter first
suppose your array was on arr, and array without duplicate is newArr

```
var newArr = [];
 arr.forEach(function(value){
    if(!newArr.some(elem => elem.id === value.id){
        newArr.push(value);
    }
})
```

after this data on the newArr can be used on the repeat identifiers with no duplicate